# Проблема с phpmailer

Tags: php, веб-программирование, phpmailer

```
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';




//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '123'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = '123'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров




$mail->setFrom('123@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('123@p33.org');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('123@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('123@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;

$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank.html');
}

?>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я ставлю require_once(class.phpmailer.php) у меня не может загрузится страница. Кто может подсказать с чем это связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала добавьте в начало файла

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Скорее всего дело в неверном пути до phpmailer.

Например в своём коде я использую напрямую подключенный phpmailer не через class.phpmailer.php, а скачанный с gitHub дистрибутив.

Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/pphpmailer/src/Exception.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/pphpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/pphpmailer/src/SMTP.php');
```

Вполне возможно что у вас он уже подключен и без require_once, например wordpress подключает phpmailer своими скриптами.

Попробуйте включить `//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` и выполнить скрипт.

Особенно полезными в отладке таких проблем вам будут логи сервера с ошибками. Где их найти - зависит от настроек хостинга/сервера/локальной машины.

Comment: только phpmailer*